# Software closing itself as soon as it opens. Only with a regular user

Tags: windows-7, permissions, users

I've seen that there have been many people who have reported an issue like the one i'm having right now but i'll explain you in detail what is happening. My problem occurs at work with an specific application called HOLOS, if i log in with my admin user account to windows 7 then this program opens without any problem but if i do it with a regular user account then happens what the title says. And yes maybe you will say that perhaps the user doesn't have the right permissions but i checked those on properties->security and it says he has full control of it.

Comment: as it's related only to one software, best would be to contact it's developer, I don't think we could identify the issue based on the information you've provided.

Comment: Check the event viewer. I've had this issue with software I've written, turns out as the app loads an exception is thrown and it just closes but the Event Viewer may shed some light. Permissions is my first guess but, see if the logs show

Comment: Yes but i was asking because another regular user is using the same program with no problem at all so i was wondering if anyone had an idea if this has something to do with active directory permissions, group policies etc. Maybe someone else had this problem. Thank you for your reply Máté Juhász

Comment: @Dave Thank you for your reply! i'll try that

Comment: Has anyone else had this issue before?

Comment: Well, it seems that the cause of this issue was that snagit 8 printer has to be placed as default printer and it wasn't otherwise if there is another printer as default then the program would close as soon as it opens and i don't know why this is happening but this resolved the issue.

Comment: How did you find this out?

Comment: It seems that some programs sometimes can't load printer drivers and crash at startup due to this conflict and even more if it's a network printer after some research i did. I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the cause of this issue was that snagit 8 printer has to be placed as default and it wasn't otherwise if there is another printer as default then the program would close as soon as it opens and i don't know why this is happening maybe it has to do with something that software developers at work made the program with but this resolved the issue.